# How can we do open a popup for login facebook and after complete it will close?

Tags: users, social-network

I want a popup that will open when anybody wants to sign-in using facebook or any social site login. The box pops up and will close after successful login or cancel

This is code I am using for this and I know something missing please give me some hint---

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MYCLIENTID&amp;redirect_uri=http%3A//www.MYWEBSITE.COM/fboauth/connect&amp;scope=email" class="facebook-action-connect" onclick="window.open(this.href,'popupwindow','width=700,height=500,scrollbar,resizable'); return false;"  target="_self" style="color: White; font-weight: bolder; cursor: hand; text-decoration: none">
```

Comment: Which module(s) are you using to log in to Facebook?  How is your login process currently set up?

Comment: Are you using D7 or D6?

Comment: I am usin D7 and facebook Oauth

Comment: And (bearing in mind the [FAQ] explicitly forbids questions asking how to build an entire feature) what have you already tried yourself?

Comment: I am successful to open a popup box using window.open in a href tag but it should be closed and take back login info, I just want any hint How to do?

Comment: We need to see the code you've already tried, then we can see where you're going wrong and help out. Please add it into the question (not in the comments)

Comment: I update my code could you check..

Answer (score 1):

You should try [ulogin](http://drupal.org/project/ulogin)...
I hope this will solve your whole problem.
:)

Description:-
uLogin service allows your users to login using their accounts at:

Facebook,
Twitter,
Google,
Windows Live ID,
LinkedIn and various open id.

Comment: Nope, I can't use any service provider login module like ulogin or any other

Comment: I there no body who can give a hint only to do that without any module of social link login provider

Comment: Dear @MohitGoyal,Please take a look at [this]
(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/).
I think this will help u out because fb changes the API on 4feb.
:)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that turned out to be the "[External Links](https://www.drupal.org/project/extlink)" module enabled. It saw the facebook url as external, and promptly added target="_blank", causing all clicks to open in a new window.